# JOOQ Java 8 Schema is Abstract and cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, sql, java-8, jooq

In the JOOQ  [documentation](http://www.jooq.org/java-8-and-sql) It says I can do this:

```
try (Connection c = getConnection()) {
    String sql = "select schema_name, is_default " +
                 "from information_schema.schemata " +
                 "order by schema_name";

    DSL.using(c)
       .fetch(sql)

       // We can use lambda expressions to map jOOQ Records
       .map(rs -> new Schema(
           rs.getValue("SCHEMA_NAME", String.class),
           rs.getValue("IS_DEFAULT", boolean.class)
       ))

       // ... and then profit from the new Collection methods
       .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

However when I do that I get the error **"org.jooq.Schema is abstract; cannot be instantiated"** - which if you look at [documentation](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Schema.html) that's true.

So how in the world is the code in the example supposed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer : they are not using ["org.jooq.Schema"](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Schema.html) in their example, but instead a static inner class.

---

If you scroll down at the bottom of [the page you linked](http://www.jooq.org/java-8-and-sql), they give github links to examples. The example you have is the [SQL goodies](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-s-Java-8-Goodies/tree/master/src/main/java/org/jooq/java8/goodies/sql) one.

If you open [SQLGoodies.java](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-s-Java-8-Goodies/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jooq/java8/goodies/sql/SQLGoodies.java) you'll notice a static inner class `Schema` at the top of the example class

```
static class Schema {
    final String schemaName;
    final boolean isDefault;

    Schema(String schemaName, boolean isDefault) {
        this.schemaName = schemaName;
        this.isDefault = isDefault;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Schema{" +
                "schemaName='" + schemaName + '\'' +
                ", isDefault=" + isDefault +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Then scroll down and you'll find your example using the inner class :

```
 DSL.using(c)
     .fetch(sql)
     .map(r -> new Schema(
            r.getValue("SCHEMA_NAME", String.class),
            r.getValue("IS_DEFAULT", boolean.class)
     ))
```